# Displaying attribute set in Magento

Tags: magento

I am new to using Magento, this is my first site using it.

I want to display the attribute set for a particular product on the product view page but cannot work out what code I need for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each attribute has a "visible on frontend" property, which you can set to true.